# Can't add custom fields to checkout

Tags: php, magento, input, magento-1.9

I have installed [Custom field in checkout](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-field-in-checkout.html) plugin and as advised by [documentation](http://magentojack.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/add-custom-field-in-checkout/) I added following code

```
<li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:ssn" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="custom[ssn]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getQuote()->getSsn()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('SSN') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" id="billing:ssn" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
```

to `persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` and to every `billing.phtml` I found, just to make sure.

However the new field doesn't show up anywhere, ctrl+f with `<input type="text" name="custom[ssn]"` on checkout page's source finds nothing.

I'm using the newest Magento version (1.9.0.1).

I'm open to other methods of adding custom fields, provided I won't need to touch Magento core files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the **Template Path Hints** in the checkout page. Check by default which template file is displaying there and add the new field to that template...............